# How to set the direction and speed of background movement by mouse click?

Tags: javascript

Why does the speed increase after each click? I'm also wondering how I can apply requestAnimationFrame here and use transform translate instead of background-position?

I need the background to move in the direction set by the cursor position and at a speed depending on the distance between the click point and the middle of the div

I set the starting position for bg

```
function flight() {
    let wmap = document.querySelector('#wmap');
    let pos1 = wmap.clientWidth;
    let pos2 = wmap.clientHeight + 800;

    wmap.style.backgroundPositionX = `${pos1}px`;
    wmap.style.backgroundPositionY = `${pos2}px`;
    // wmap.style.translate = `${pos1}, ${pos2}`;

    let v, v1;
    let x0, y0;
```

then set the center of the div

```
 wmap.addEventListener('mouseover', takeOff);
    
    function takeOff(e) {
        console.log(e.offsetX);
        x0 = 350;
        y0 = 350;
    }
```

and made it move

```
wmap.addEventListener('mousedown',move);

 function move(e) {
        console.log(e);
        v = -(e.offsetX - x0);
        v1 = -(e.offsetY - y0);
        console.log(v, v1);
        setInterval(moveBg, 20);
    }
    function moveBg() {
        pos1 += v * 0.01;
        pos2 += v1 * 0.01;
        wmap.style.backgroundPositionX = `${pos1}px`;
        wmap.style.backgroundPositionY = `${pos2}px`;
    }
}
flight();
```

here's an example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fl2UYJzu2PaFD1CIrm-ed_yFXlY5putR/view?usp=share_link

Comment: You keep creating new event listeners every mouse move. Try moving `wmap.addEventListener('mousedown',move);` outside off the `takeOff` function

Comment: Also, you are thinking "procedurally" (this happens, and then this happens) when you should be thinking "event drivenly". .... Aside: what do you expect from this line `setInterval(moveBg, 20);`?

Comment: @GetSet Was trying to get this to move all the time, I need a smooth movement in a given direction after each press

Comment: @Reyno I moved it out of the function, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Scrap this code and start from scratch. Get the motion done first so that everything moves without mouse interaction. Then place conditions on the motion based on booleans, e.g. `if (motionFLAG) { ...update x,y...}`. Then change the state of the booleans based on mouse interaction only where needed.

Comment: @MisterJojo I added an example of how it works

Comment: @MisterJojo I already moved the listener out of the function, after the comment above. i guess i should edit the question

Comment: @MisterJojo but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add at the beginning of the flight function: `let movement;`

```js
 function move(e) {
       clearInterval(movement); //add this
        
        console.log(e);
        v = -(e.offsetX - x0);
        v1 = -(e.offsetY - y0);
        console.log(v, v1);
        movement = setInterval(moveBg, 20);//correct this
    }
```